# how to restrict for For Loop for only one value in aura controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

my requiremen is:
i have different forms like ' contract release' , release1, 'release2', 'release3'....
Below My code is working perfectly ...........But i need to restrict for only 'Contract Release' Form

"""""""""""""   if(d.Form == "Contract Release"){ """"""""""""""".

But this is working for other forms also....
Can you pls help me how to restrict for only Contract Release .

```
saveDataTable :function(component, event) {
 
   var editedRecords =  component.find("riderStatusDataTable").get("v.draftValues");
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(editedRecords);
    //alert(myJSON);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < editedRecords.length; i++) { 
        var TemporaryArray;
        TemporaryArray = {'sobjectType':'Reader_Status__c'};
       
       /////////New code added///////////////
      var data = component.get("v.data"); 
      var uptData = [];
      var  TemporaryArray1 = {'sobjectType':'Reader_Status__c'}; 
      var  TemporaryArray2 = {'sobjectType':'Reader_Status__c'}; 
      var  TemporaryArray3 = {'sobjectType':'Reader_Status__c'}; 
      var editedRecords1 =  component.find("riderStatusDataTable").get("v.draftValues");
        if(data.find(record => record.Form === 'Contract Release')){
           TemporaryArray1.Date_Sent__c = editedRecords1[0].Date_Sent;
           TemporaryArray1.Date_Reviewed__c = editedRecords1[0].Date_Reviewed;}

    for (var x in data)
            {
              var d = data[x];
                if(d.Form == "60 Day Follow Up Letter" ){
                    var dt = new Date(TemporaryArray1.Date_Sent__c);
                    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 61);
                    d.Date_Sent = dt;
                    dt = new Date(TemporaryArray1.Date_Reviewed__c);
                    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 61);
                    d.Date_Reviewed  =  dt;
                  TemporaryArray2.Id = d.Id; 
                  TemporaryArray2.Date_Sent__c = d.Date_Sent;
                  TemporaryArray2.Date_Reviewed__c = d.Date_Reviewed;
                  uptData.push(TemporaryArray2); 
                  alert(TemporaryArray2.Date_Sent__c);
                   alert(TemporaryArray2.Date_Reviewed__c); 


                
                  }
            if(d.Form == "120 Day Follow Up Letter" ){
                var dt = new Date(TemporaryArray1.Date_Sent__c);
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 121);
                d.Date_Sent = dt;
                dt = new Date(TemporaryArray1.Date_Reviewed__c);
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 121);
                d.Date_Reviewed  =  dt;
              TemporaryArray3.Id = d.Id; 
              TemporaryArray3.Date_Sent__c = d.Date_Sent;
              TemporaryArray3.Date_Reviewed__c = d.Date_Reviewed;
              uptData.push(TemporaryArray3);
             alert(TemporaryArray3.Date_Sent__c);
               alert(TemporaryArray3.Date_Reviewed__c);     
            }
            
            component.set("v.data",uptData);
           
        } 
      //End new code////////////// 
         TemporaryArray.Id=editedRecords[i].Id;
        TemporaryArray.Date_Sent__c=editedRecords[i].Date_Sent;
        TemporaryArray.Send_To__c=editedRecords[i].SendTo;
        TemporaryArray.Date_Reviewed__c=editedRecords[i].Date_Reviewed;
        var totalRecordEdited = editedRecords.length;
        var action = component.get("c.updateRiderStatus");
        action.setParams({
            'data':uptData,
            'editedRiderStatusList' : TemporaryArray
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                if(response.getReturnValue() === true){
                    var message = totalRecordEdited+" Contract maintaenance Records Updated";
                    component.set("v.notifysection",true);
                    component.set("v.notificationmessage",message);
                 /////
                    component.set("v.data",uptData);
                // ///
                    // to redirect to the Quote request page
                    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                    navEvt.setParams({ 
                        "recordId": component.get("v.parentRecordId"),
                        "slideDevName": "detail"
                    });
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        navEvt.fire();
                    },1000);
                    
                } else{ //if update got failed
                    component.set("v.notifysection",true);
                    component.set("v.notificationmessage","Error in update");
                     
                }
        }
           
    });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        
    }
    
},
```

Thanks
VRK

Comment: Hi this issue is not resolved...can you pls help on this. I am unable to restrict to only form ' Contract Release' . Current code working for all other forms also

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the data entry is the edited entry, but instead iterating all values over all edits, each one will match. You're probably looking for something like this:

```
var data = component.get("v.data");
var releaseForm = data.find(record => record.Form === 'Contract Release');
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response..can i tried something like this: var data = component.get("v.data"); 
        var releaseForm = data.find(record => record.Form === 'Contract Release'); 
   var  TemporaryArray1 = {'sobjectType':'Reader_Status__c'}; 
    var editedRecords1 =  component.find("riderStatusDataTable").get("v.draftValues");
   var uptData = [];
   if(releaseForm){
    TemporaryArray1.Date_Sent__c = editedRecords1[0].Date_Sent;
                  TemporaryArray1.Date_Reviewed__c = editedRecords1[0].Date_Reviewed;
      break;
     } But no use...can u pls exploan more

Comment: Why do you keep calling it an array? It's not an array, definitely confusing to read your source. Also, please edit your question instead of putting code in comments, it's hard to read.

Comment: Yes source code edited, pls review the source code and let me know whats wrong in this. Need to restrict only for Form ''Contract Release'' . But current functionality is working for all other forms also .

Comment: This issue is not resolved...can some one pls help on this